# Dealing with a huge dataset in Docker

Tags: python, docker, dataset

I'm currently using a remote computer for the training of my image segmentation models (written in python). I have an important dataset (approximatively 40GB) on which I would like to train a model.
I have to use Docker for the training on the remote computer.

**MY ISSUE**

There is no BUG.
However, I have disk memory issues as each time that create the docker image, all data are saved into the image which duplicates the dataset size.

I don't know if I use correctly Docker and if there is a better way to deal with the datasets with docker (maybe with an additionnal volume).

**WHAT I'AM DOING**

Here is my DockerFile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.1.0-gpu-py3

RUN mkdir /AI_PLATFORM
WORKDIR /AI_PLATFORM

COPY ./install.sh ./install.sh
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
COPY ./computer_vision ./computer_vision
COPY ./data ./data
COPY ./weights ./weights
RUN bash install.sh
```

All my training data is saved in the `./data` folder.

The `install.sh` contains the following lines:

```
#!/urs/bin/env bash

apt-get update
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then, when I want to create a new image and to launch a training, I run the following commands:

```
docker build -t ai_platform .
docker run --gpus all --env NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 -v $PWD/weights:/AI_PLATFORM/weights --rm -it ai_platform python computer_vision/segmentation/unet_segmentation_models.py
```

I use the `-v $PWD/weights:/AI_PLATFORM/weights` to save the obtained weights on the remote computer (so that they are not deleted after a training).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What about bind mounting the data inside the container exactly as you do for your result folder ?

Comment: Thank you for your response and help @Zeitounator I think that it would work but is it the best way to proceed ?

Comment: Although you can perfectly challenge this solution depending on your exact requirements, your available infrastructure... it will always be far better than copying 40GB worth of data inside an image which is supposed to be portable.

Comment: I think that I had to add ```COPY ./weights ./weights``` into my DockerFile too so that it works.. so I am not sure that the solution will work (if I delete the ````COPY ./weights ./weights```)

Comment: If you copy something in the image and then bind mount at the same location when you start your container, the content of the image will be obfuscated by the one from the bind mount. And I'm not talking about `weights` in my above comment, but about data you should not copy at all if this is 40GB IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it worked without using the ```COPY```parameter and using ```-v``` instead